# First character not read while reading file from server

Tags: java, android

Following is my piece of code which read file from server in string. But it is not reading first character in file.

For example:
Firstline in my file is: 9,0

But when i read it i got result: ",0"

```
URL uurl = new URL(this.m_FilePath);

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uurl.openStream()));
                 in.read();
                String str;
                while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    text_file=text_file+str;
                    text_file=text_file+"\n";
                }
                in.close();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove this statement which is reading the first byte from the `InputStream`

```
in.read();
```

Answer (score 1):

why  `in.read();`? no need that. remove it. that will consume first byte in your text.